# replace pattern *

Tags: linux, sed, awk, tr

I'm trying to add an "`*`" character at the position 72 if line starts by "`LOADS*`" and last caracter of the line is not an "`*`" and also add a new line with an "`*`" character at column 1.

**INPUT**

```
LOAD*   720010013       1.5             1.0300          710010013
LOAD*   730010013       1.5             1.0300          710010013       *
*       10.73           1000001
LOAD*   720010014       1.5             1.0300          710010014       *
*
LOAD*   730010014       1.5             1.0300          710010014       *
*       10.73           1000001
LOAD        10013       1.5             1.0300              10013
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LOAD*   720010013       1.5             1.0300          710010013       *
*
LOAD*   730010013       1.5             1.0300          710010013       *
*       10.73           1000001
LOAD*   720010014       1.5             1.0300          710010014       *
*
LOAD*   730010014       1.5             1.0300          710010014       *
*       10.73           1000001
LOAD        10013       1.5             1.0300              10013
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
awk '/^LOAD\*/{if (substr($0,73,1)!="*"){x=sprintf("%-72s%c",substr($0,0,72), "*"); $0=x "\n*";}}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^LOAD\*.*[^*]$/!b;:a;/.\{72\}/!s/$/ /;ta;s/\(.\{72\}\).*/\1*\n*/' file
```

N.B. Using your test data the `*` appears to wanted at col 73.